# Add class to current (clicked) element in nested map statement

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add class to the selected element using state. I've tried the following but this adds it to each of the questions I just need it to add it to the question being answered. I am using react class components and redux. I've also tried passing in an index in the outer map statement and adding that to the index value from the second map statement to see if that would then select options from the current question.

```
    return totalQuestions.map((q) => {                  
                return (
                    <div key={q.id} id={q.id}>
                        <h2 className={this.state.title}>{q.title}</h2>
                        <h3>{q.questionText}</h3>
                        <div key={q.id}>
                            {q.options.map((opt, index) => (
                                < div
                                    key={opt.id}
                                    val={opt.val}
                                    ref={this.options}                                  
                                    className={`${index === this.props.dataPersisted.clickedItem ? this.state.selected : ""} ${this.state.options}`}                                    >
                                    <div>
                                        <p onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}                                                                                     
                                            ref={this.correctRef}                                       
                                        >
                                            {opt.text}                                              
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>

                        <PopUp
                            onRef={ref => (this.PopUp = ref)}
                            correct={this.state.correct}
                            pop={q.feedback}
                        />
                        <button
                            className={this.state.submit}
                            onClick={this.checkAnswer}
                            ref={this.checkAnsRef}
                        >
                            Check Answer
              </button>
                    </div >
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected element data of a question should be maintained per question instead of a single this.props.dataPersisted.clickedItem.
I have created [a working Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/PGLcShkszCZnMwVg?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1) Please checkout
For ex:

```
className={`${index === this.props.dataPersisted[q.id]? this.state.selected : ""} ${this.state.options}`}>
```

Comment: Thanks mate but the only problem is I can't access q.id from the handleclick function? The handleclick function is setting this this.props.dataPersisted.clickedItem = index;

Comment: store as like below:.  this.props.dataPersisted[index].clickedItem = index;

Comment: Hey,  you need to change your expression as:  className={`${index === this.props.dataPersisted[index].clickedItem ? this.state.selected : ""} ${this.state.options}`}>

Comment: I have created a working plunker and updated in the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: mate thank you so much! works like a charm! so much harder than jquery though hey!

Comment: How do I do that? I did vote but it won't accept it as I have no rating.